# Undeleted answer on deleted question shows as deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

There seems to be a minor bug exhibiting itself when viewing a deleted question with an undeleted answer - the undeleted answer also shows as deleted.

Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249577/application-css-manifests-require-tree-is-working-but-requiring-individual-fil has been deleted and the one answer is marked as "deleted by Bohemian". However looking at the revision history of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25250045/revisions it shows that it has been undeleted since Bohemian's deletion.

In this case given the question is deleted the display probably doesn't matter too much so this isn't an important bug. However I am well aware that sometimes serious problems can be found when investigating unimportant seeming bugs so I felt this was worth making sure it was properly recorded.

Comment: The question is deleted. All answers under a deleted post are considered deleted too.

Comment: Ah, ok. Who does it normally indicate deleted an answer in that case out of interest?

Comment: If you see a different time or a name that deleted it

Comment: @Chris: no name is displayed in that case. It just shows as *deleted <date of question deletion>*

Comment: In that case what I've described still sounds like unintended behaviour rather than by design but at the same time I can also understand it could also be "won't fix" or similar given how minor it is. :)